# Is there a way to have a storyboard default to landscape in Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard, xcode8

Storyboards in Xcode8 now show a device preview instead of the 'abstract' preview they showed before.

This preview defaults to 'portrait'. You can switch it to landscape, but the switch doesn't persist— even going to another file and immediately back to a given storyboard will reset the view to portrait.

Is there a way to say "my app only supports landscape, can you please stay in landscape"?

Comment: I just keep the storyboard open in a single tab. It allows to keep landscape view even after XCode's relaunch.

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this seems to be changing the "Simulated Size" parameter to "Fixed".

Not sure if there's a better way. This looks to be an Xcode bug…(?)

[image: Screenshot of relevant part of Xcode interface]

Answer (score 0):

You can select orientation in the bottom left of the IB clicking on "View as: ***"

[image: IB]